# UWP ListView Prevent Scrolling When Item Inserted At Index 0

Tags: xaml, listview, scroll, win-universal-app, uwp

I have UWP/Windows 10 app. It contains a ListView bound to an observable collection. The list view contains items in a reverse chronological order (newest at the top).

Often when new items arrive I need to insert them at the top of the collection. This works fine, the item is inserted and the list view updates with the new item via the binding mechansim.

My problem is if the list view is already scrolled to the top of the list, the new item animates in and pushes all the other items down. This is problematic for many reasons, but one big user annoyance is they were often just about to click on the top item and it changes underneath them at the last millisecond and they end up clicking on the wrong item.

If the list is already scrolled down at least the height of the top item, there is no problem. The item is inserted at the top of the list, the scrollbar updates to indicate you can now scroll up further than you could before, but the vertical scroll position of the list does not move and the visible area/viewport remains unchanged.

This is the same behaviour I want when the top item in the list is visible and a new item is inserted before it. The vertical scroll position/view port should remain unchanged, the scrollbar should update to indicate you can now scroll up, and doing so should reveal the new item.

Does anyone know how to obtain this behaviour?

UPDATE: So my problem is slightly more complicated than I first thought. The new item is inserted at position zero, and the list does not scroll (if it is already scrolled down 1 pixel or more). That's great. However, if the item is subsequently updated (async loading of extra data), and this causes the item template height to change then the list scrolls when the data updates.

For example;

```
Item1 (top of visible list)
Item1 line 2
Item2
Item2 line 2

Then new item added

Item0 (not visible)
Item0 line 2
Item1 (top of visible list)
Item1 line 2
Item2
Item2 line 2

All good. Now item0 updates and it's line 2 becomes a much longer piece of text that wraps;

Item0 
Item0 AAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (List scrolls so everything from here down is now visible)
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Item1 (no longer top of visible list)
Item1 line 2
Item2
Item2 line 2
```

EDIT 2: 
I do not have a physical phone to test with at the moment, but I've just tried this in the Windows 10 Mobile emulator and the behaviour there is the one I want. With even a small part of the first item scroll off the screen, adding a new item that increases it's height shortly after load doesn't cause the view port to scroll at all. However the behaviour I don't want still occurs on the desktop. This is very disappointing from a "universal" app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listviews default ItemsPanel has a property called **ItemsUpdatingScrollMode**. You can set it to **KeepItemsInView**.

You still have to scroll down by at least one pixel beforehand, what can be achieved using the ListViews internal **ScrollViewer**'s **ChangeView**.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" />
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want, and it is in fact the default behaviour (I checked the items panel in use at runtime, and the property is already set this way). Unfortunately while it works for the simple case, it doesn't work for my actual real-world scenario. See my edited question for the second half of the problem.

Comment: We'll, you either found a bug in the listview, or your case just isn't covered by the default implementation. You can create your own Panel, doing the calculation on your own, or (and probably better) not change the list items size after they were added. (YouTube changes the list after it has loaded and it sucks there too...)

Comment: I'm going to accept this since it technically answsers the question as first posed, even though it doesn't solve my actual problem. Not changing the list item size isn't really an option - I want that data in the list, but I can't (and shouldn't) retrieve it synchronously.

Comment: Given the behaviour on W10 mobile is what I want, and different to the desktop version, I think this is a bug... but whether the bug is in the desktop or mobile version, and whether it will ever be fixed are completely different questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ListView function `ScrollIntoView` for this. General problem is, that this function only assures the Listitem is shown, not where the item is shown.(at top/bottom of the ListView)

But you can use a small trick to achieve this:

1: Remember the item, that should be shown

```
firstitem = ItemListView.Items(0)
```

2: When inserting an item before this, make sure the Listview scrolls in a way that the item from (1:) is shown at the top

```
'Your Insert Function
ItemListView.Items.Insert(0, "test") '<-- Your Insert function

'Scroll in a way that the item from (1:) is shown on top
ItemListView.ScrollIntoView(ItemListView.Items(ItemListView.Items.Count - 1))
ItemListView.UpdateLayout()
ItemListView.ScrollIntoView(firstitem)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I should have mentioned that I tried this already, but it often (not always) caused flicking and display issues as the list scrolled around. I'm looking for a way to prevent the scrolling in the first place, rather than trying to undo it after the fact.

Comment: By the way, I believe if you want to use this solution you can skip the first ScrollIntoView call. Keep the updatelayout(), then make one scroll into view call using the overload that takes two arguments and specify 'leadingedge';

ItemListView.ScrollIntoView(firstitem, ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Leading)

The second argument says scroll so the top edge of the item is inline with the top edge of the list box, there by scrolling just enough to keep 'firstitem' at the top. This reduces (but doesn't elimiante flicker) and doesn't cause items near the end of the list to be realised.

Comment: So that is the solution? Because in my case I use the VisualTreeHelper to get the scrollviewer, get the TransformToVisual matrix and then ChangeView, the issue is that you need to capture the controls instantiated.